# How to position <h1> element on the same line as navigation links?

Tags: css, html

Sorry for a beginners question. I'm trying to position my navigation bar along the same 'line' as the  element. In this case 'title'. Basically just trying to get it to appear on the one line in the header.

HTML:

```
<header role="banner">
            <h1>
            <a href ="#" title="Title" rel ="home">Title</a>
        </h1>
<!--Navigation Start-->
        <nav role ="navigation">
            <div class ="navigation-menu-container">
                <ul id ="navigation-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Skills &amp; Field of Interests</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
<!--Navigation End-->
```

CSS:

```
a:link{

    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #ecf0f1;

}

a:hover {

   text-decoration: underline;
    color: #ecf0f1;
}

a:visited {

    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #ecf0f1;
h1
{
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

    .navigation-menu-container {


        padding: 30px;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }


    #navigation-menu {

        text-align: justify;
        padding: 20px;

    }

    #navigation-menu * {

        display: inline;
    }

    #navigation-menu li {

        display: inline-block;    
        padding-right: 35px;
    }

    #navigation-menu span {

        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Well the `h*` tags are `block-level` elements by default. Meaning, that they take up as much horizontal space as their parent.

Answer (score 7):

Add `display: inline` to your `h1` tag. This should fix it.

The reason it doesn't work how it is, is that `h1` tags are set to `display: block` by default, which means they will take up as much horizontal space as their parent element.

Setting it to `display: inline`, (or `display: inline-block`)* overrides the default style and makes it able to get "inline" with other "inline" elements.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju77U/) that displays my point.

*`inline-block` is different than `inline` in that `inline` won't let you set width or height.

Comment: Thank you for explicitly explaining that by default h1 tags are display: block. Not only am I excited it worked, but also happy to understand why! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use display: inline:

CSS:

```
h1
{
    display:inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KJKuC/

Answer (score -2):

To make two block elements align (`h1` and `nav`), you can make both `float: left`: http://jsfiddle.net/xPq2Q/1/

In this example, I also adjusted some paddings.

Comment: Who downvoted my answer and why? Btw, of course it doesn't work if your viewport isn't wide enough.